# Maximum Entropy for Natural Language Processing

Tags: statistics, nlp, named-entity-recognition

Can anyone explain simply how how maximum entropy models work when used in Natural Language Processing. I need to statistically parse simple words and phrases to try to figure out the likelihood of specific words and what objects they refer to or what phrases they are contained within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the NLTK python package. You can also use MALLET or WEKA.
For a theoretical background, you should ask at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or http://metaoptimize.com/qa/ .